# Bounded generic parameters in Play Framework template

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

How can I use bounded generic parameters in a Scala template within a Play Framework 2.3 Java project?

I currently have something like:

```
@(entities: List[_ <: Entity], currentEntity: Entity)

<ul>
    @for(entity <- entities) {
        @if(currentEntity.equals(entity)) {
            <li><strong>@entity</strong></li>
        } else {
            <li>@entity</li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

However, I can call this with different types of entities in `entities` and `currentEntity` - which is not nice. I would like to do something like:

```
@[T <: Entity](entities: List[T], currentEntity: T)
...
```

But this gives me `Invalid '@' symbol` as a compile error.

Comment: It's [not supported currently](https://github.com/playframework/twirl/issues/37).

Comment: That's a pity. But thanks for the fast reply! Maybe there is a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @m-z points out, it's not supported (yet). But you might be able to get the type-safety you desire (at the cost of another family of classes) by marshalling your arguments into a View object first:

```
case class HighlightedListView[E <: Entity](entities:List[E], currentEntity:E)
```

Now in your controller, load up a new `HighlightedListView` instance instead of feeding the parameters straight to the template:

```
 def foo = Action {
  ...
  // Assuming some SubEntity exists, the compiler will enforce the typing:
  val hlv = HighlightedListView[SubEntity](entities, currentEntity)


  Ok(html.mytemplate(hlv))
```

}

As the comment states, the compiler will barf if your types don't line up. Then the template can be pretty loose with types, because we know we're safe:

```
@(hlv:HighlightedListView[_])

<ul>
    @for(entity <- hlv.entities) {
        @if(hlv.currentEntity.equals(entity)) {
            <li><strong>@entity</strong></li>
        } else {
            <li>@entity</li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

You can even take advantage of your new `View` object to add helper methods, which can make for easier-to-read templates, and facilitate unit testing:

```
case class HighlightedListView[E <: Entity](entities:List[E], currentEntity:E) {
   def shouldHighlight(e:Any):Boolean = currentEntity.equals(e)
}
```

leading to:

```
 @if(hlv.shouldHighlight(entity)) {
     <li><strong>@entity</strong></li>
 } else {
     <li>@entity</li>
 }
```

Comment: For me this only worked with a type member, not a type argument